# VB ListBox.Items throwing compile error

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am trying to read all selected items from a listbox in Visual Basic.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim testValue As String
testValue = "20"

For x = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count() - 1
      If Me.ListBox1.Items.Item(x) = testValue Then
            MessageBox.Show ("Found it")
            Exit Sub
      End If
Next x
```

is the code I am trying. But When I run the code, I am getting "Compile error :
Method or data member not found"

I guess I am missing some references to use "ListBox.Items" method right?
What is the required references/library.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code into a new project. Added a form with a ListBox. Ran the code and it worked perfectly.

Are you sure the problem is in this part of the project?

Comment: Hi Brian, When I run the code, I am getting "Compile error : Method or data member not found". Can you please share the list of references you are using in the project?